# Javaassist Proxy-Class without Constructor

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist

I currently use Javaassist to generate a proxy for a class:

```
ProxyFactory f = new ProxyFactory();
f.setSuperclass(JFrame.class); // Just an example.

// I would like to create a proxy for JFrame to
// fill with method implementations...
f.setHandler(handler); // ... in an own handler

Class<?> proxyClazz = f.createClass();
```

My problem is: The JFrame constructor is also called. Makes sense. But I dont want this. I would like to generate an empty class as proxy which is assign-compatible to other normal JFrames.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you for all ideas and thoughts.

Comment: No, the superclass constructor has to be called.

Comment: Not really. There is 3 different way to create class without invoking constructor.

Comment: @talex : you meant `create object instance of given class type` when you said `create class` ?

Comment: @rkosegi yes. Exactly.

Comment: Isn't this achievable using built-in JDK [Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and [InvocationHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Serialization

You can create array of bytes representing required class in serialized form and use `ObjectInputStream.readObject`.

This is possible but it is hard to prepare correct data.

2. `NativeConstructorAccessorImpl`

This is how `spy` method is implemented in `mockito`.

3. `Unsafe.allocateInstance`

So you prepare your proxy class and instantiate it one of those method (or some other way).

**PS**: Take a look on [`objenesis`](http://objenesis.org/) library.

Comment: Thank you talex! This is exactly what I searched for!